# Class path exception on raspberry pi but not on any other PC

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, classpath

I have been building a point of service application for a friend and have gotten to the stage of implementing it.
My computer, and the computer of those who have been testing for me have had no problem running the program. However, when I tried to implement it on the raspberry pi running archlinux arm and java 8—which is the same as my pc, other than the arm archetecture—I run into a class path exception.    Specifically:

```
could not find or load main class TOC19.Interface
```

I have tried loading with -cp {. or TOC19} and changing the mannifest file to no avail.

The jar file I am using can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5jqfasn88qxkh4/TOC19.jar?dl=0
and the source code can be found here: https://github.com/jarrah-95/TOC19

Thanks for the help.